# How can I test a Python module that I ran in the the text editor in the Python console?

Tags: python

I have a Python script that I named moduleA.py in the text editor. I ran the script by clicking the "Run Script" button. Then I expected to be able to import the module in the console with "import moduleA" but I get an error saying that the module does not exist.

How does one test functions etc. from a Python script in the text editor in the Python console?

Comment: @batFINGER Is this really the same? This is about testing a script in the Python Console, not importing modules to another script.

Comment: @RayMairlot Prior to change could import `py` extension text editor script eg `moduleA.py`  into the python console with `import moduleA` now instead use `moduleA = bpy.data.texts["moduleA.py"].as_module()`  _Don't necessarily need to run script from text editor first_